# How do I get around this error while running aws-azure-login

Tags: npm

binding.cwd();
^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_cwd
at Error (native)
at Object.posix.resolve (path.js:424:50)
at Function.Module._resolveLookupPaths (module.js:250:17)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:317:31)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:26:13
at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:76:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem, it has nothing to do with aws-zure-login. I just exited my terminal and it all worked. Looks like an npm issue